# How to convert an array to xts

Tags: r, xts

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('AAPL')
n <- nrow(AAPL)
a <- runif(n)
```

I would like to convert `a` to an xts object with dates equal to the dates of `AAPL`.

So far I wasn't able to do it by any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple:

```
a <- xts(runif(nrow(AAPL)), index(AAPL))
```